# Java thesauraus

Tags: java, dictionary

Does anyone know where I can access and use a thesaurus using Java?

I want to be able to use it in Java and use it to get similar words, based on a given word. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426746/an-online-dictionary-api-in-json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple google search -- http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php

I would use the Jersey RESTful library to do the API calls. http://jersey.java.net/

Its a very simple Java library.

In fact, once you start using Jersey you will begin making more and more demanding service calls. For example you can create a service on your web server so that others can retrieve your data, so on and so on...

Answer (score 1):

A service implementation would be your best bet - this way you don't have to maintain the dictionary yourself.

There is one at http://innovatiq.com/services/theSaurus.asmx?op=GetSynonyms.

There are quite a few more available by googling `thesaurus web service`.